# Error ’Unable to initialize remote proxy for extension.' while trying to pick documents using "UIDocumentPickerViewController"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to pick document from "Files" app using `UIDocumentPickerViewController` but sometime I get `’Unable to initialize remote proxy for extension. The connection was interrupted’` error message with blank screen. Why this is happening? How can I fix this?

Code snippet :

```
NSArray *arrContents = @[@"public.content",@"public.item",@"public.composite-content",@"public.data",@"public.database",@"public.calendar-event",@"public.message",@"public.presentation",@"public.contact",@"public.archive",@"public.disk-image",@"public.text",@"public.plain-text",@"public.utf8-plain-text",@"public.utf16-external-plain-​text",@"public.utf16-plain-text",@"com.apple.traditional-mac-​plain-text",@"public.rtf"];

UIDocumentPickerViewController *dvc = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc]initWithDocumentTypes:arrContents inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
dvc.delegate = self;
dvc.allowsMultipleSelection = true;
[self presentViewController:dvc animated:true completion:nil];
```

Screenshot :
[image]

Comment: can you please share your code arrContents?

Comment: NSArray *arrContents = @[@"public.content",@"public.item",@"public.composite-content",@"public.data",@"public.database",@"public.calendar-event",@"public.message",@"public.presentation",@"public.contact",@"public.archive",@"public.disk-image",@"public.text",@"public.plain-text",@"public.utf8-plain-text",@"public.utf16-external-plain-​text",@"public.utf16-plain-text",@"com.apple.traditional-mac-​plain-text",@"public.rtf"];